# MongoDB Connection Issue over SSL

Tags: mongodb, birt

I am Not able to connect mongoDB which is over the SSL. Without SSL its working fine.
I tried to ping from datasource connection setting, but its failing. Additionally I have imported public certificate to my jvm keystore.

mongodb connection url that I'm trying with is, 
mongodb://[user]:[password]@[hostname]:[port]/[database]?ssl=true

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: BIRT is giving following exception- 
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
    com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /ip:port/admin

 at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.existsDatabase(MDbConnection.java:246)

 at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.mongodb.impl.MDbConnection.getMongoDatabase(MDbConnection.java:83)

Answer (score 1):

Here, the issue is with ODA driver, which wasn't supporting the SSL based mongo.
Solution is to add mongo-java driver version  2.13.1 to BirtRuntime and delete existing ODA driver org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb_2.10.1.v20130422-1135.jar.

Once done, connect to mongo using connection url, mongodb://[user]:[password]@[hostname]:[port]/[database]?ssl=true